# Time series graph is showing ascending line in Jupyter Phyton

Tags: python, graph, jupyter-notebook

The y-axis ranges from -4 to +4 and even then appears increasing over time

[image]

This chart is from Excel and this is how it should look:

[image]

Here I show following the python script:

[image]

[image]

[image]

It looks like python doesn't recognize the numbers.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I see that the datatype of the series you obtained by extracting the column `"ONI"` is showing it as an object and this is because the numbers are separated by a comma instead of a period (assuming they are decimals). I think fixing that might fix the issue. Try the following lines of code:

```
elnino["ONI"] = elnino.ONI.str.replace(",", ".")
```

Also if you want a wider graph like the one from Excel that you showed, you might want to set the required plot dimensions. You can either do this by passing in an additional `figsize = (a,b)` parameters and pass in the dimensions for the size of the figure as a tuple or you can specify a certain width by using the `plt.figure().set_figwidth(a)` method.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Before I even saw your answer, I had switched from a comma to a dot in the CSV file. What solved this problem.